# Adding an id on mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I am trying to join 2 tables and then return the result, below is the code I use.
The problem is, lets say I want to grab the row only from 'Tina' to 'Ben'. It will not be possible since it has no ids, if I somehow include their ids, it will be in random numbers and not in orders.  Is there anyway to handle this type of issue?

```
SELECT names.name, COUNT(item) AS items
FROM names
LEFT JOIN names_items 
  ON names.name = names_items.name
GROUP BY names.name
ORDER BY COUNT(item) DESC
```

The result would be something like this.

```
| Names  | Items  |
  Bob       60
  Tina      32
  Arthur    43
  Ben       21
  Ronie     54
```

Comment: You can use where clause in this case.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you know the order of the rows you can use limit

Comment: I can use limit, I have no problem with that but what if I want to get only the results from 'Tina' to 'Ben'

Comment: What is the criteria that defines the rows you want to grab?

Comment: You should order them first. Then use `where` clause or `limit` if the specified rows are for example the first three rows.

Comment: Can you show it then? How would you grab the results from 'Tina' to 'Ben'

Comment: Can you ask a proper question first? How should the query decide which rows to grab?

Comment: You cannot limit the results whithout ordering them depending on a particuler criteria.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a column  while creating all those table make the column name id and the properties of id will be

```
-> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

then you can use this id to select  what u want

Answer (score 2):

You might try adding "WHERE names.name in ('Tina', 'Ben', 'Arthur')?

This is based on you wanting Tina, Ben, and Arthur's information.

Or LIMIT (2,x) (Where x is the distance between Tina and Ben)

This only works if Tina is ALWAYS the second record, and Ben is ALWAYS the same distance from Tina AND always comes after Tina.

A more complicated way to do it would be to:

1. set the table you have in the OP to be a temporary table.
2. select the count where name = 'tina' as var1 and select items where name = 'ben' as var2
3. do a case where var1 > var2 - select * where count < var1 and count > 2 else select * where count > var1 and count < var2

I don't think there is a "good" solution to this question, and it would be easier to answer if we knew WHY you were wanting everyone between Ben and Tina...is there something special about Ben and Tina?